# SQLite3 account creator

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

This program allows users to create and log into their account. The database is created using SQLite3 and the GUI is just simple tkinter boxes. I just want to know how to improve my code, organise it, make it more efficient.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
with sqlite3.connect("User.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
                userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
                )""")


def login(usernameLogin, passwordLogin):
    while True:
        username = usernameLogin.get()#Asks for username
        password = passwordLogin.get()#Asks for password
        with sqlite3.connect("User.db") as db:#Creates a connection to database
            c = db.cursor()
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")#Validates inputs for account
        c.execute(find_user,[(username),(password)])
        results = c.fetchall()#Fetches values from database

        if results:#Validates if the username/password is recognised
            for i in results:
                messagebox.showinfo("", "Welcome "+i[1]+"!")
            break

        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Password and username is not recognised")
            break

def newUser(username1, password1):
    found = 0
    while found == 0:
        username = username1.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("User.db") as db:
            c = db.cursor()
        findUser = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?")
        c.execute(findUser, [(username)])#Checks existence of username in database

        if c.fetchall():
            messagebox.showinfo("Username", "Username taken please try again.")
            break
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Account has been created!")
            found = 1

    password = password1.get()
    insertData = '''INSERT INTO user(username, password)
    VALUES(?,?)'''#Inserts new account into databse
    c.execute(insertData, [(username),(password)])
    db.commit()

def newUserTkinter():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Create new account")

    labelOne = ttk.Label(window, text = "Enter a username:")
    labelOne.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    username1 = tkinter.StringVar(window)#value type is classified as a string
    usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width = 30, textvariable = username1)
    usernameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text = "Enter a password:")
    labelTwo.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    password1 = tkinter.StringVar(window)#value type is classified as a string
    passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width = 30, textvariable = password1)
    passwordEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    btn = ttk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=lambda: newUser(username1, password1))
    btn.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

def menu():
    with sqlite3.connect("User.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
    print(c.fetchall())

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Treasure Hunt Game!")

    labelOne = ttk.Label(window, text = """ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ USER MENU ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    """)#label displays instruction
    labelOne.grid(row = 0, column = 0)#places label in a grid

    btn = ttk.Button(window, text = "Create account", command = newUserTkinter)
    btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)#places button in a grid

    labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text = "Login to your account:")
    labelTwo.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    usernameLogin = tkinter.StringVar(window)#value type is classified as a string
    usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width = 30, textvariable = usernameLogin)
    usernameEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

    labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text = "Username")
    labelTwo.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    passwordLogin = tkinter.StringVar(window)#value type is classified as a string
    passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width = 30, textvariable = passwordLogin)
    passwordEntry.grid(row = 6, column = 0)

    labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text = "Password")
    labelTwo.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

    btn = ttk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=lambda: login(usernameLogin, passwordLogin))
    btn.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Review

- Read PEP8 the python style guide, you have some style issues

  1. functions and variables should be `snake_case`
  2. Group your imports
- You can import multiple items from the same module on 1 line => `from x import y, z`
- Some comments are irrelevant and only add noise to the code

  `username = usernameLogin.get()#Asks for username`

  This line is perfectly self-explanatory and there is no need for that comment
- Secondly I find `code#commentblock` hard to read

  Instead I would add a docstring, or at least put the comment above the code for clarity
- As you do with the `connection` you can use the `cursor` as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)

### Hashing

When handling passwords you should *at least* [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) them,

preferably with a well tested hashing algorithm such as [bcrypt](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/)